# IIS 7 http bindings option is missing

Tags: windows-7, http, .net-framework, iis, bindings

I'm having trouble figuring this out, the bindings option in my IIS is missing.

This is what I did before the problem.
 Step 1. install Windows 7 Professional on a new hard drive.
 Step 2. Install Visual studio 2012 Rc and All .NET frameworks, 4.0 4.5 RC.
 Step 3. Install IIS with all Application Develoment Features.
 Step 4. Open IIS, and try to set bindings on website under default website. But cant because there is no option for the bindings. no button.. no nothing.

I can see the bindings option on the default website but even if I try to set something there is does not work.

I googled this of course and found the same issue on the IIS forum http://forums.iis.net/t/1155799.aspx

They talk about there that you have to have Windows Process Activation Service installed before you install IIS. I found out that I did not have it installed and it isn't default in windows 7.

so I uninstalled the IIS, installed WPAS and then installed IIS. but with no luck.

Then they talk about you have to have WCF Activation installed under Microsoft .Net framework 3.0. (I have 3.5.1)

So I uninstall everything, install everything under .NET 3.5.1 features like "Windows Communication foundation HTTP Activation and Windows Communication foundation NON-HTTP Activation.

And with it WPAS and IIS.

Restart... and still no luck !

I have tried uninstalling the frameworks and install them again with no success.

I'm really stuck now and the next step would be to format the drive and install everything again, but I would really like to not have to do that.

I would be really grateful if you guys could help me find a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know this topic is very old, but there was the same problem I have just fixed myself, and by searching I found this topic, so I hope other users searching for resolution of this problem will see my post. In my case it was IIS 8, but for IIS 7 it should work, too. I have encountered the problem after Windows 8.1 updates.

What I did to resolve this problem, was uninstalling not just "Internet Information Services" and "Windows Process Activation Service", but also "Internet Information Services Hostable Web Core". After that, I have restarted my computer, reinstalled everything I have just mentioned, and everything worked fine - application pools were recreated, default website added along with all the bindings. I hope this helps!

Comment: It works like a charm.